# How can I display the next letters of a select field value?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a select field

```js
$('#myselect').on('change' , function() {
  var a = $('#result'); 
  select = $(this).val();  // Get the value  
  selectValue=$(this).find(':selected').data("value");   
  a.find('.b').html(selectValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select id="myselect" style="" name="select[]" class="select">
         <option data-value="ABC">My product</option>
         <option data-value="BCD">My second product</option>
   </select>

   <div id="result">
   <span class="b"></span>
   </div>
```

So the results would be "ABC" and "BCD" and instead I want to display "BCD" for the first one,  and "CDE" for the second.. so the next letters of the displayed value in english alphabet..

Any help would be appreciated ...

**Edit :**
In the answers given below, when there is a Z in the options, it displays ]. The function that returns -26 if it's a z doesn't seem to work. So I mixed up the code snippets and came up with a result that seems to work.

```js
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  let result = [...$(this).find('option:checked').data('value')].map(
    (letter) => {
      if (letter == "z") {
          return "a";
        } else if (letter == "Z") {
          return "A";
        } else {
          return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
        }
    }).join('');
    
  $('#result .b').text(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select id="myselect" style="" name="select[]" class="select">
         <option data-value="ABC">My product</option>
         <option data-value="XYZ">My second product</option>
   </select>

   <div id="result">
   <span class="b"></span>
   </div>
```

Comment: You want to "*display the next letters*"? How do you define the "next letter," the "next letter" to what? Which alphabet, all of them (somehow) or a specific language?

Comment: Thank you David, sorry I edited my question to be more precise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, with explanatory comments in the JavaScript code:

```js
// we select the element with the id of 'myselect', and
// bind the anonymous function of the on() method as the
// event-handler for the 'change' event:
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {

  // we use the spread syntax, with an Array-literal, to
  // we use the CSS selector 'option:checked' to find the
  // <option> element that has been selected, retrieve its
  // value and then convert that iterable String into an
  // Array using the spread syntax with an Array-literal;
  // we then call Array.prototype.map() to create a new
  // Array based on the first:
  let result = [...$(this).find('option:checked').val()].map(
    // within the map() method, we use an anonymous Arrow
    // function to pass in the current letter of the String:
    (letter) => {
      // we use String.prototype.charCodeAt() to retrieve the
      // the char-code of the current letter (passing an index
      // of zero to do so, as it's the only letter and
      // JavaScript is zero-based):
      let characterCode = letter.charCodeAt(0),
          // to retrieve the char-code of the next letter
          // I assumed that we should wrap around to 'A'/'a'
          // if the current letter is 'Z'/'z':
          // we first find if the Array of numbers 90 and 122
          // (the char codes for 'Z' and 'z' respectively);
          // if so we subtract 26 from the character code (to
          // return the 'A' of the relevant case, or if not
          // we return the character-code + 1:
          nextCode = [90, 122].includes(characterCode) ? characterCode - 26 : characterCode + 1;
          
      // here we return the next letter through the use of
      // String.prototype.fromCharCode() and passing in the
      // nextCode variable:
      return String.fromCharCode(nextCode);
    // we then use Array.prototype.join() to create a String
    // from the Array of letters:
    }).join('');
    
  // selecting the element(s) with a class-name of 'b' that are
  // nested within the element with an id of 'result':
  $('#result .b').text(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="select[]" class="select">
  <option value="ABC" data-value="ABC">My product</option>
  <option value="BCD" data-value="BCD">My second product</option>
</select>

<div id="result">
  <span class="b"></span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jwu58h92/3).

This is, of course, perfectly possible in plain JavaScript without use of a library, as follows:

```js
// utility functions to reduce repetetive typing (I don't enjoy typing 'document.querySelector...'
// all that much:
const D = document,
    get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
    getAll = (selector, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)];

// here we retrieve the element with an id of 'myselect' and use EventTarget.addEventListener()
// to bind the anonymous function as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
get('#myselect').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  // here we retrieve the element within the evt.currentTarget (the element
  // to which the event-handler is bound) that matches the 'option:checked'
  // CSS selector, retrieve its value and then trim() leading and trailing
  // white-space:
  let result = [...get('option:checked', evt.currentTarget).value.trim()].map(
    // as above, we use the anonymous function of the Array.prototype.map() 
    // method, passing in a reference to the current letter of the Array of
    // letters:
    (letter) => {
      // retrieve the char-code of the current letter:
      let characterCode = letter.charCodeAt(0),
          // determine if the current letter is a 'Z'/'z', and if so we
          // subtract 26 (to get an 'a' of the correct case), otherwise
          // we add a 1 to get the next char-code:
          nextCode = [90, 122].includes(characterCode) ? characterCode - 26 : characterCode + 1;
      // returning the String created from that nextCode value:
      return String.fromCharCode(nextCode);
    // and join the Array of letters back to an Array:
    }).join('');
  // retrieving the first - if any - element(s) that match the supplied
  // CSS selector, and update the textContent of that element to be
  // equal to the newly-created String:
  get('#result .b').textContent = result;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="select[]" class="select">
  <option value="ABC" data-value="ABC">My product</option>
  <option value="BCD" data-value="BCD">My second product</option>
</select>

<div id="result">
  <span class="b"></span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jwu58h92/4/).

Of course the use of `change` does require that the user select a value other than the starting value (assuming that they wish the starting value to be their choice), so I'd suggest an adjusted HTML:

```js
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  let result = [...$(this).find('option:checked').val()].map(
    (letter) => {
      let characterCode = letter.charCodeAt(0),
          nextCode = [90, 122].includes(characterCode) ? characterCode - 26 : characterCode + 1;
          
      return String.fromCharCode(nextCode);
    }).join('');
    
  $('#result .b').text(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select id="myselect" name="select[]" class="select">
  <!-- here we use an <option> element that is both selected, so that it's shown on
       page-load, and disabled so that it can't be selected by the user once the
       select has been opened; forcing them to choose one of the other options: -->
  <option selected disabled>Please select:</option>
  <option value="ABC" data-value="ABC">My product</option>
  <option value="BCD" data-value="BCD">My second product</option>
</select>

<div id="result">
  <span class="b"></span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jwu58h92/5/).

References:

*CSS:

- [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)
  *JavaScript:
- [Array-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).
- [`String.prototype.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: hello David, thanks again for your help, it works great.. I have a particular case, when the letter is Z, it becomes "]"... compared to your last code, do you know if there is something to do to return to the letter "A" instead of the Z? I understood that it took this specific case into account, but it doesn't work if I have a Z as the letter..

Comment: I corrected my mistake; essentially in the ternary I *had*: `nextCode = [90, 122].includes(letter)`, which was testing for `a`, `b`, ... being included in the Array of numbers, instead of what I *intended* which was to use `nextCode = [90, 122].includes(characterCode)`. I do apologise; the code in the answer has been edited and corrected, and the JS Fiddle links now point to corrected demos.

Comment: thank you very much David, in your example I get "@" instead of "A" if I run your fiddle...in the last example I provided, do you think it's correct ? because it's working but  I don't know if from the point of view of the code it is correct or optimized ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you mean get value for next element or what , if i understand right this code will work for you

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myselect").change(function() {
        var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var nextOption = selectedOption.next();
    var a = $('#result');
    a.find('.b').html(nextOption.data("value"));

      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <select id="myselect" style="" name="select[]" class="select">
             <option data-value="ABC">My product</option>
             <option data-value="BCD">My second product</option>
             <option data-value="CDE">My Third product</option>
       </select>

       <div id="result">
       <span class="b"></span>
       </div>
```

Comment: or you mean replace first letter for selected item with next letter in alphabet

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i can't choose all the answers that works perfectly, so i added an upvote for each of you, and marked as solution the most complete answer..really thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your request correctly but the code below, from what I understood of course, should be able to help you.

```
$(function(){

$('#myselect').on('change' , function() {

    let nbLetter    = 3;
    let beginCode   = $(this).find(':selected').data("value").charCodeAt(0);
    let myValue     = "";

    // Construct New Value
    for(let i=0;i<nbLetter;i++) myValue += String.fromCharCode(beginCode+1+i);

    console.log(myValue);
});

});
```